# How to make SQL query with Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, model, sql, resource-model

This is part of the aw blog module. 
I have 2 tables.

```
aw_blog
post_id | tags
1 tag1
2 tag2
3 tag3

aw_blog_post_cat
cat_id | post_id
1 1
1 3
2 3
```

I have that SQL statement and i am trying to do it with magento way:

```
SELECT `aw_blog`.`tags` FROM `aw_blog_post_cat` RIGHT JOIN  `aw_blog` on `aw_blog`.`post_id`=`aw_blog_post_cat`.`post_id` WHERE `aw_blog_post_cat`.`cat_id`=1
```

I tried something like that:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('blog/blog')->getCollection()
->getSelect()->joinRight(array("post_cat" => $this->getTable('aw_blog_post_cat')), 'main_table.post_id = post_cat.post_id', array());
```

from that [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)
But with no luck.
There is no model implemented for `aw_blog_post_cat` table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't test because I don't have the module installed on a Magento installation but I checked the source code and I am not sure if it is latest one.
You have in the collection of the Blog class AW_Blog_Model_Mysql4_Blog_Collection a method which helps to filter the content based on the category id

```
class AW_Blog_Model_Mysql4_Blog_Collection
...
public function addCatFilter($catId)
{
    $this->getSelect()->join(
        array('cat_table' => $this->getTable('post_cat')),
        'main_table.post_id = cat_table.post_id',
        array()
    )
    ->where('cat_table.cat_id = ?', $catId);

    return $this;
}
```

Then you can use in your code that:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('blog/blog')->getCollection()
    ->addCatFilter(1);

$items = $collection->getItems();
```

So now you get all post items.

Comment: this is the correct answer. nicely done sylvain

Comment: @SanderMangel I replaced the collection of `cat` by the one of the `blog` which has the same filter. It should display the tags. @philwinkle thx

Answer (score 3):

The Fishpig blog has an excellent article about [writing custom queries](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/).
It explains in detail how to get the query resources and tablenames.

In your case it would be something like this

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$results = $read->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM {$resource->getTableName('blog/post_cat')}"); // change the query to your needs

var_dump($results);
```